# Atifa as creation of an ohel

Tags: halacha, melacha-creative-work, tallit-gadol, boneh-soter

Here's a question from a discussion over Shabbat.

*Boneh* (building) is an a melachah of Shabbat, particularly any variant in which an *ohel* (tent) is erected. However, one of the common methods of *atifat hatallit* (wrapping the tallit) has the appearance of erecting an ohel.

As such, based on this (admittedly shaky) progression, is atifa considered to be boneh by any authorities?

Answer (score 3):

If the Talis would be a very thick material which does not flop over when held up, it would be Ohel. This is the way the Taz (and similarly the Magen Avraham) explain the opinion of the rishonim brought in siman 301 siff 40. They are subsequently brought in later achronim like Mishna Berurah 151.

The Taz 27 specifically mentions Atifa, and the Magen Avraham 51 discusses placing one's Talis up over their hat, where the tallis hangs down like walls.